# Designing table to store the transaction entry in a double entry accounting database

Tags: database-design, accounting

I try to develope a small accounting system using codeigniter.
Case I: The database have 2 tables: `tbl_transaction` and `tbl_journal` to record daily transactions.
ie, in `tbl_journal` the `date, amount, narration` of the transaction will be stored and the `tbl_transaction` contains the `journal_id, account, amount`accounts involved in each transaction, which means there will be 2 entries in `tbl_transaction`, one entry showing `positive amount` & other showing `negative amount` with the debit/credit account name.
Case II: The database with single table `tbl_journal` to store the transaction information. ie, `tbl_journal` with fields for `date, amount, debit account, credit account, narration`.
Which of these would be good?  Or what could be the better design?
Somebody please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is better. In accounting you get cases where one Credit entry is matched by multiple debit entries, and vice versa. Your second option wouldn't cover that.

Comment: In that case, should i use 2 seperate tables, instead of single 'tbl_transaction', to record credit side and debit side respectively? Or will it be better if i make 2 entries for credit and debit in my 'tbl_transaction' ??

Comment: one more help please...Why is it better if using 2 tables instead of one??I mean how is it helpful while generating further reports??